# SQL Algorithm to Manipulate a string based on a Code Pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Sql Code is as  follows ,

```
Declare @text nvarchar(max) = 'America,Japan,Indonesia,London'
Declare @Pattern nvarchar(20) = '1001'
```

So For this Pattern  the sql function should return the string as **'America,London'**
The String should be manipulated based on the pattern and the corresponding comma  seperated text should be removed if the pattern character is  0.

Expected Sample Output:

```
@Pattern           @Text
1100               'America,Japan'
1000               'America'
0100               'Japan'
1111               'America,Japan,Indonesia,London'
```

What is  the  Efficient way  to acheive this  results in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Is the source text always exactly four(4) names separated by columns?

Comment: Will it always have four cities? or it can be more?

Comment: convert the strings to an xml list and then use xml queries on them.  or better yet, have your front end send xml.

Comment: No RBarry. The cities can  be  more .It doesnt have  a fixed four cities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a Parse/Split Function

```
Declare @text nvarchar(max) = 'America,Japan,Indonesia,London'
Declare @Pattern nvarchar(20) = '1001'

Select NewString = Stuff((Select  ',' +RetVal 
  From (Select A.RetSeq,A.RetVal 
         From (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@Text,',')) A
         Join (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](Stuff(Replace(Replace(@Pattern,'0',',0'),'1',',1'),1,1,''),',')) B
           on (A.RetSeq=B.RetSeq and B.RetVal=1)
     ) A
  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

Returns

```
NewString
America,London
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```